# Replace a string content with other content PHP

Tags: php, string

I have an a string declared at the top of my PHP script:

```
$dirname = "./rootfs/home/".$user."/";
```

After running the code, that string should be replace so it looks like this:

```
$dirname = "./rootfs/home/".$user."/testdir/";
```

Is there any way to replace the content? This is a dumb question for sure, but didn't found any way to do it, thanks! :D

Code I'm using:
Main PHP:

```
<?php

//Variables
$rootfs = "rootfs/";
$user = "www";
$dirname = "./rootfs/home/".$user."/";

//Variables

//Commands on rootfs/bin/
include($rootfs."/bin/ls.php");
include($rootfs."/bin/about.php");
include($rootfs."/bin/echo.php");
include($rootfs."/bin/uname.php");
include($rootfs."/bin/apt-get.php");
include($rootfs."/bin/whoami.php");
include($rootfs."/bin/cd.php");
//Commands on rootfs/bin/

$command=$_POST['command'];

$commandexp = explode(" ", $command);

switch ($commandexp[0]) {
case "cd":
    //$dirname = "./rootfs/home/".$user."/";
    //$prompt = cd($dirname, $commandexp[1]);
    $dirname .= cd($dirname, $commandexp[1]);
    echo $dirname;
    break;
case "ls":
    switch ($commandexp[1]) {
    case "-la":
        //$dirname = "./rootfs/home/".$user."/";
        $files = ls($dirname);
        foreach($files as $value){
            $prompt .= substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($dirname.$value)), -4)."   ".$user."   ".$value."<br>";
        }
        break;
    case "--help":
        $prompt = "Usage: ls [-la]";
        break;
    default:
    echo $dirname." ";
        $files = ls($dirname);
        foreach($files as $value){
            $prompt .= $value." ";
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
default:
    $prompt = "command not found";

}

echo $prompt;

?>
```

The cd.php

```
<?php
function cd($actualdir, $dir) {
    //echo $actualdir.$dir."<br>";
    if(file_exists($actualdir.$dir)) {
        echo $dir;
        return $dir;
    } else {
        return "no";
    }
}

?>
```

The ls.php

```
<?php
function ls ($directory) {

    // create an array to hold directory list
    $results = array();

    // create a handler for the directory
    $handler = opendir($directory);
    echo $handler;
    // open directory and walk through the filenames
    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {

        // if file isn't this directory or its parent, add it to the results
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $results[] = $file;
        }

    }

    // tidy up: close the handler
    closedir($handler);

    // done!
    return $results;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used a session variable for storing the actual dir

Answer (score 2):

To add a string just do that:

```
$dirname .= "/testdir/";
```

Comment: Yeah I tried, but when echoing it later, the string seems the same :/

Comment: Added main files, check it out

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate one string to the end of another string: `$dirname .= 'testdir/'`
To reassign a totally new string to the variable: `$dirname = 'This is the new string'`
See [String Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Yeah I tried, but when echoing it later, the string seems the same :/

Comment: Added main files, check it out

Comment: Does PHP reach the `cd` function line? what's the return value from `cd`?

Comment: ./rootfs/home/www/testdir/ that's what `cd` return when writing `cd testdir`. But when writing `ls`it returns the contents of the old string always

Comment: @zad0xsis: That's because when writing `ls`, the PHP code doesn't change the value of `$dirname`

Comment: but isn't supposed to be changed when typing `cd`?

Comment: Yes, that happened on different script execution. In PHP, every script has it's own variables which are destroyed at the end of execution. The variables don't keep their value for another execution. That's why most scripts initialize variables (mostly configuration variables).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
$dirname .= "testdir/";
```

Comment: Yeah I tried, but when echoing it later, the string seems the same :/